# how to convert object to list in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, list

Here is my Input
Could you all help me out to get the all object based on values as list

```js
{
    Jack: 2,
    olive: 1,
    harry: 2
}
```

Want my output to be

```js
harry = 2          
olive = 1
jack  = 2
```

Let me know if there is a way to get the output as mentioned above  in javascript

Comment: By mentioning list u need to print as html?

Comment: Or u just need to console.log it?

Comment: why this strange order ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the function `Object.entries(object)` and loop over all the entries to log the information how you want.

For more information on Object.entries(object) visit https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

```
const data = {
  Jack: 2,
  olive: 1,
  harry: 2
};

const entries = Object.entries(data);

entries.forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(`${key} = ${value}`));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
const result = Object.entries(theObject).map(([key, value]) => `${key.toLowerCase((} = ${value}`).join(‘\n’);
console.log(result);
```

Hopefully that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Please check Object.entries() or Object.keys().

**Object.entries():-** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

**Object.keys():-** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Answer (score 0):

**I know I'm probably not answering the question but, this just shows it in the DOM instead of the console.
If you want an ordered list just change the `<ul>` (opening and closing tags) to `<ol>`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    
<div class="output"></div>


<script>
const data = {
  Jack: 2,
  Olive: 1,
  Harry: 2
};
const entries = Object.entries(data);
let output = '<h1> Output </h1>';

entries.forEach(([key, value]) => {
output += `<ul>
    <li> ${key} = ${value} </li>
    </ul>`;
   document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = output;
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```